# How to send mail in apache camel with attachment and file size validation using DataHandler and FileDataSource

Tags: email, apache-camel

Error while sending mail to the recipients with attachment in apache camel 
    Note :ajay.jpeg is present inside the src/main/resources of images folder
    absolute path works but relative path fails.

```
@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
   exchange.getIn().addAttachment("ajay.jpeg",
   new DataHandler(new FileDataSource("images/ajay.jpeg")));        
}
```

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: images\ajay.jpeg (The system cannot find the path specified)

Answer (score 1):

```
Finally got the solution after multiple tries.

  private final DataSource ds = new URLDataSource(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("images/ajay.jpeg"));    
        @Override
        public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {           
            try
            {           
                Message in = exchange.getIn();
                in.addAttachment("ajay.jpeg",new DataHandler(ds));  
                if(in.getBody()!=null) {
                    String payload=in.getBody(String.class);    

                    if((payload.length()) <= (1048576)) {
                    in.addAttachment("data.txt", new DataHandler(payload,"text/html"));
                    }else {
                        log.info("file size is More  than 1 mb");   

                    }
                }

            }catch(Exception e) {
                log.error("exception occured in processing the mail cause : msg {}",e.getCause(),e.getMessage());
            }   

        }
```